# Robolectric - Error Copying SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-context, robolectric

I am currently testing the Android API, and to do so, I have developed an application that copies a database that I have made beforehand and testing that application (which calls on several Android classes). Someone directed me to using Robolectric to get coverage of the Android source, however, this has caused some problems. My application runs just fine without it, as well as my test, but now I'm running into errors with the copying of my database. Whenever I run the test, my catch gives me an error from copying the database, and taking out that catch results in an AssertionFailureError

```
assertTrue(activity.accessAdapter() != null);
assertTrue(activity.accessAdapter().accessHelper().checkDatabase()); // Here
```

I'm assuming that has something to do with not getting the database copied, as if I put back in the try-catches I had in my code, it results back in setting them off when copying the database.

Here's the code for my SQLiteOpenHelper, or at least what gets called up in copying the database.

```
public void createDatabase() throws IOException
{
    this.getReadableDatabase();
    this.close();
    try {
        copyDatabase();
        Log.e(TAG, "Database created.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Error("Error copying database.");
    }
}

private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
    InputStream input = ((ShadowContextWrapper) shadowContext).getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
    String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    input.close();
}
```

I assumed the problem might have to do with the context, so I created a ShadowContext, but that didn't really help either. There are other errors, but those are just methods that call each other up all the way down to the createDatabase() in my SQLiteOpenHelper.

Does anyone know how I can copy this database using Robolectric? I have it saved in assets for my application, but obviously, without the emulator, this is pointless. Thank you.

P.S. I can add any more code if necessary, this is just what I thought was necessary at first.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this problem? I'm having exactly the same.